# Jquery to Native JS: Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

sorry for disturb, I have a problem.. I am trying to convert a script in JQuery to Javascript, but I get this problem:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined"

Original script (Jquery):

```
$("div.mainMenu li").click(function() {
            var subId = $(this).attr("id");
            $("div.mainMenu").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
            $("div.mainMenu").find("li#" + subId).addClass("active");
            $("div.bottomMenu").find("ul").css('display', 'none');
            $("div.bottomMenu").find("ul." + subId).css('display', 'block');
        });
```

My script with the error:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.mainMenu li'), function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // code
            var subId = this.getAttribute("id");
    document.querySelector('div.mainMenu li.active').classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById(subId).classList.add("active");
     document.querySelector("div.bottomMenu ul").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector("div.bottomMenu ul."+subId).style.display = 'block';


            }) })
```

Where is the error? 
Now it works in part, there is a problem with the sub-menu, if I click the second tab the menu the sub-menu load good, but if I return in the first tab of menu the sub-menu is the first sub-menu + the second sub-menu!

Thank you for the help! ^^

Comment: `.queryAll()` returns a **list** of elements, not just one.

Comment: And `.queryAll` has been deprecated and removed from the spec

Comment: @Pointy mh, what i could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function(){
  //get the menu lis and convert to array for forEach usage
  var mainMenuLi = toArray( document.querySelectorAll( 'div.mainMenu li' ) );
  //get bottom menu and convert to array for forEach usage
  var bottomMenuUl = toArray( document.querySelectorAll( 'div.bottomMenu ul' ) );
  
  //extract this so can call just this method
  function toArray ( elements ) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call( elements, function ( element ) {
      return element;
    } );
  }
  
  function menuSelection ( e ) {
    //if the id of the li does not match the clicked elements id, remove active
    mainMenuLi.forEach( function ( li ) {
      if ( li.id === e.target.id ) {
        li.classList.add( 'active' );
      } else {
        li.classList.remove( 'active' );
      }
    } );
    
    //if the id of the clicked element is not on the bottom menu ul, hide it
    bottomMenuUl.forEach( function ( ul ) {
      if ( ul.classList.contains( e.target.id ) ) {
        ul.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        ul.style.display = 'none';
      }
    } );
  }
  
  //bind the click handler to all the lis
  mainMenuLi.forEach( function ( li ) {
    li.addEventListener( 'click', menuSelection );
  } );
})();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help me, it gives that error now:" Uncaught ReferenceError: bottomMenuUi is not defined" @Taplar

Comment: I have got other problem, i putted the code in other page and it gives me that error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function", but if I include that code in another page it works perfectly!

Do you know why?
There are other method, for it works?

I think the function ToArray() go in contrast with other functions!
Sorry really for the disturb!

Comment: "each" is a jQuery method.  Sounds like you are trying to use a jQuery method on a non jQuery object some where.

Comment: Probabily yes, there isn't other methods for it works without the function ToArray()?

Because I can't remove the js in question, in that case all functions will not work.

I am really sorry for disturb you, again thank you for the support if you can help me again! ;)

Comment: You could potentially use [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: @Endless :O, you're my new favorite person!  Though no IE support yet, :(

Comment: IE is dead... Better would be `for..of` instead of forEach but that requires es6

Comment: @Endless, where I can use Array#from?
I didn't understand good! ;)

Comment: Instead of the `toArray` function you change it to `Array.from`

Answer (score 0):

Now it works in part, there is a problem with the sub-menu, if I click the second tab of menu the sub-menu load good, but if I return in the first tab of menu the sub-menu is the first sub-menu + the second sub-menu!

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.mainMenu li'), function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // code
        var subId = this.getAttribute("id");
        document.querySelector('div.mainMenu li.active').classList.remove('active');
        document.getElementById(subId).classList.add("active");
        document.querySelector("div.bottomMenu ul").style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector("div.bottomMenu ul."+subId).style.display = 'block';
    })
})
```

Where is the error..? I don't understand, is like the original code but in vanilla javascript!